# Ordering listview after adding new items?

Tags: android, listview, twitter, android-listview

I've managed to update new items to `listview`. But, i want to add them to top instead of bottom.

To be more clear, initially my `listview` will show  only 2 tweets. If i hit refresh, it will update and show next 2 tweets along with old 2 tweets.

**Initially** (It shows 2 tweets):

[image]

**After refreshing** (old tweets in down + new 2 tweets at top) :

[image]

By using this code, managed to show new items at top

```
 feeds.add(0,b);
```

My problem is, i want the latest tweet to appear at first. But, here latest tweets went to 2nd position and 2nd tweet went to 1st position.

Example :

Consider the initial listView with 2 item as

```
Tweet 1 ,
Tweet 2 .
```

I got 2 new tweet and im gonna adding to listview. 2 new tweets are,

```
Tweet 1_new,
Tweet 2_new.
```

Expected result,

```
Tweet 1_new,
Tweet 2_new,
Tweet 1 ,
Tweet 2 .
```

Current result,

```
Tweet 2_new,
Tweet 1_new,
Tweet 1 ,
Tweet 2 .
```

The first new tweet goes to bottom and second tweet to top. I hope you got it.

Code to add new data to listview :

```
 for (twitter4j.Status status : statuses) {
           System.out.println(status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" +
                    status.getText() + " | Retweet count : " + status.getRetweetCount());

            Bean b = new Bean();
            b.setsName(status.getUser().getScreenName());
            b.setTweet(status.getText());
            b.setImageurl(status.getUser().getOriginalProfileImageURL());


            System.out.println("size : " +t);

            feeds.add(0,b);
      }
```

In this iteration, the first latest tweet goes to bottom & the last tweet to top. I just want the reverse of it. Latest at top, last at bottom.

Comment: You want an automatic update of the ListView and insertion of the new items at the top. Right?

Comment: I implemented Pull to refresh. When i refresh new items are added but latest one goes to down and last one goes to top. I want the correct ordering after hitting refresh.

Comment: Please post your cursor's getView() method.

Comment: Why cursor's getview? I've a ArrayList & added all new items. Refreshed to show new items through notifydatasetchanged() function.

Comment: Through bean class and ArrayList. I pass paramters manually through static datas and i add that bean to ArrayList.

Comment: It seems to be a problem in your logic. Why not calling `ArrayList.add(int, Object)` in reversed order than? Or calling `ArrayList.addAll(int, Collection)`?

Comment: @biegleux : may i know how to call that in reverse order? Wait i add that part of code.

Comment: `for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Bean> newBeans = new ArrayList<Bean>();
for (twitter4j.Status status : statuses) {
    ...
    newBeans.add(b);
}
feeds.addAll(0, newBeans);
```

Comment: your answer is being flagged as low quality. Please add an explanation on what is wrong and why this code works. It's useful for readers and will prevent deletion.